# Xbox controller disconnecting with Unity on iOS projcet

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, xbox

I am making a VR unity project, however since I don't own a VR headset, the headset is my phone in a cardboard box, and I am receiving input from an xbox controller. When I connect the xbox controller to my laptop, it works fine with the game, but when I connect it to the phone, it connects at first, but after two seconds disconnects. I am using unity remote 5, I have an iPhone 13 Pro, and my unity editor version is 2022.3.9f1

I used this code to detect if the controller is connected or not:

```
private bool connected = false;

IEnumerator CheckForControllers() {
    while (true) {
        var controllers = Input.GetJoystickNames();
        if (!connected && controllers.Length > 0) {
            connected = true;
            Debug.Log("Connected");
        } else if (connected && controllers.Length == 0) {
            connected = false;
            Debug.Log("Disconnected");
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    }
}

void Awake() {
    StartCoroutine(CheckForControllers());
}
```

This is what the console shows when the phone is connected:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cA5BQ.png)
And this is what it says when the phone is not connected (I waited for 30 seconds before stopping the program):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaa2O.png)

I used this code to detect if the controller is connected or not:

```
private bool connected = false;

IEnumerator CheckForControllers() {
    while (true) {
        var controllers = Input.GetJoystickNames();
        if (!connected && controllers.Length > 0) {
            connected = true;
            Debug.Log("Connected");
        } else if (connected && controllers.Length == 0) {
            connected = false;
            Debug.Log("Disconnected");
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    }
}

void Awake() {
    StartCoroutine(CheckForControllers());
}
```

This is what the console shows when the phone is connected:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cA5BQ.png
And this is what it says when the phone is not connected (I waited for 30 seconds before stopping the program):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaa2O.png